# Spring Batch, Access StepExecution in the writer()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I recently posed this question, but I don't think I was explicit enough on what my goal was.

I have a step that consists of a reader, processor and writer.

The `writer()` is a `CompositeItemWriter`, consisting of two `JdbcBatchItemWriter`. In one of these I'm writing to a control table that will contain a `row_count` column. This value needs to come from `StepExecution.getReadCount()`.

I'm new to Spring Batch so I'm unsure how you add a listener that can wrap a `StepExecution` to the actual writer itself.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `@BeforeStep` [annotated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/annotation/BeforeStep.html) method.

This method is called before the first item is writen and spring should pass the StepExecution into it.

```
@BeforeStep
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though it doesnt really make sense? BeforeStep will run before the step will execute? If the step hasnt executed then will the readCount be 0?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this functionality through afterStep
and there read, write, skip and batch status will be available.
class will be as:

```
@StepScope  
public class GcblRptAccItemListener {  
        @AfterStep  
        public ExitStatus afterWrite(StepExecution stepExecution) {  
            stepExecution.getReadCount();  
            stepExecution.getWriteCount();  
            return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;  
        }  
}
```

and you have to configue this class where other reader and writer are configured